Is there any way to run an background scheduled task in windows so that I can show daily notification from my Flutter Application
I have an windows and macOS application where I want to show local notification daily at a specific time. Notifications are handled by a package called windows_notification: ^1.2.0 now I want to call this notification either the app is running or not.
final _winNotifyPlugin = WindowsNotification(applicationId: "AUMID");

      const String template = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <toast launch='conversationId=9813' activationType="background">
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Some text</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
        <action content='Archive'  arguments='action:archive'/>
    </actions>
</toast>

The above code provides a way to create a notification however I want to notify the users at the specific time daily weather the app is running or not
